# Use two lists of variables to add scala columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Seqs that I want to use to add columns to a dataframe.

Seq one is something like:
`Seq("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "violet")`

and Seq two is something like:
`Seq("child", "teen", "adult", "senior")`

I also have a column that is a string that is in the format of: s"$color+$age-score=$score", containing every combination of the colors and ages, with a resulting score, so 20 different color-age scores.

Currently, I am doing something like

```
finalDF.withColumn("red_child", getScore("red", "child"))
.withColumn("red_teen", getScore("red", "teen"))
.withColumn("red_adult", getScore("red", "adult"))
```

and so on, for all 20 possible combinations, with getScore being a helper function that takes care of the regex.

Since I am using withColumn 20 times, it makes the code very hard to read. I am wondering if there is any way to make this code look more clean, using the two Seqs for color and age to loop and add the columns to the dataframe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply `select` additional columns derived from the Tuple list generated using `for-comprehension`, as shown below:

```
val colors = Seq("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "violet")
val ageGroups = Seq("child", "teen", "adult", "senior")

val colPairs = for { c <- colors; a <- ageGroups } yield (c, a)

def getScore(c: String, a: String): Column = ???

df.select( df.columns.map(col) ++ colPairs.map{ case (c, a) =>
    getScore(c, a).as(c + "_" + a)
  }: _*
)
```

Alternatively, use `foldLeft` to traverse the colPairs list to add columns via `withColumn`:

```
colPairs.foldLeft(df){ case (accDF, (c, a)) =>
  accDF.withColumn(c + "_" + a, getScore(c, a))
}
```